# layer.addSublayer vs layer.insertSublayer animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cabasicanimation

I am animating a CAGradient as so

```
let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 5.0
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = [
        UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 88/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red: 196/255, green: 70/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    ]
    gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradientLayer.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
```

And it works fine when I add it to the view using this method

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

However, it is now blocking all of my UI buttons and icons, so I attempt to insert it underneath these items with

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

But when I do this, the animation stops working completely

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I impress myself with my own stupidity. I had a test picture of a gradient to work with while I was building the interface in my storyboard. The new, animated gradient, obviously went below the test picture as it should, and was hidden from sight.